# Разница между data и notification в Google Cloud Messages

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messages

В Android приложении у меня есть сервис который слушает оповещения.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.e(TAG, "New message: " + data);

    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    sendNotification(message);
}
```

проблема в том что этот метод может слушать только сообщения такого вида

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'data',
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 10000,

    data: {
        message: 'Message from gcm server',
    }   

});
```

Т.е. данное сообщение я могу отловить в приложении и выдать самостоятельно нужное оповещение.

Но если я отправляю сообщение в таком формате

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'data',
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 10000,

    notification: {
        title: "Hello, World",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        body: "This is a notification that will be displayed ASAP."
    }
});
```

То в приложении метод  `onMessageReceived()` вообще получается что не отрабатывает.

В документации написано  что  я могу отправлять гибридные сообщения которые как я понимаю  должны обрабатываться методом `onMessageReceived()`

> Hybrid messages with both notification and data payload
>
> App behavior when receiving messages that include both notification
>   and data payloads depends on whether the app is in the background, or
>   the foreground —essentially, whether or not it is active at the time
>   of receipt.
>
> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the
>   notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps
>   on the notification. When in the foreground, your app receives a
>   bundle with both payloads available. Here is a JSON-formatted message
>   can containing both notification and data:
>
> {
>       "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
>       "notification" : {
>         "body" : "great match!",
>         "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
>         "icon" : "myicon"
>       },
>       "data" : {
>         "Nick" : "Mario",
>         "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
>       }   }

Вопрос как такое может быть, и как мне можно отлавливать сообщения последнего типа?

Comment: А зачем вам его обрабатывать? Это же легкое сообщение, которое сразу попадает в нотификации без какого-либо доп кода, типа фича такая. Добавьте к нему `click_action` (см. в доках подробнее) и все. Остальное шлите и обрабатывайте через data...

Comment: В принципе вы правы, вот на счет click_action  - где про него можно прочитать потому что в доке сказано что на него можно нажать и выполнить нужное действие, но как это сделать я не нашол!?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" и в intent-filter <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще есть два состояния push-notification

- **когда приложение открыто**

тогда push обрабатывается в методе `onMessageReceived()` и там как ты распарсил все поля из `notification` делаешь свою notification и показываешь, а в теле (`data`)
там его кладешь в `intent` и по клику по `notification` открываешь `activity` сразу с нужным `intent` (В этот момент нужно точно проработать вид json чтобы не было проблем с данными).

- **второе - это когда приложение закрыто**

тогда приложение не знает что пришёл `push` , но об этом знает система, и тогда поле `notification` распарсивается системой и выстраивается `push-уведомление`, в поле `click_action` можно указать какую активность открывать(**TAG**), а в своем приложении в `manifest` прописать этой активности **TAG**, тогда система сама открое его и в нем сразу будет лежать `intent`, сформированный системой из тела(`data`)

А вся остальная работа с `intent` будет на ваших плечах.

И совет от себя, переходи на FirebaseCloudMessage, отличная обертка над gcm.

Comment: Спасибо,   с notifications уже разобрался,  Firebase уже использую!